# MySQL Case / Count / Distinct Anomalous Results

Tags: mysql, count, case, distinct

I am getting anomalous / incorrect results from the following MySQL query:

```
`select CarrierID, CarrierName,
count(distinct case when CaseYear = '2022'then CaseNumber Else 0 end) as '2022',
count(distinct case when CaseYear = '2021'then CaseNumber Else 0 end) as '2021',
count(distinct case when CaseYear = '2020'then CaseNumber Else 0 end) as '2020'
from SalesRegister where CarrierName like 'Grange%'
group by CarrierName order by 3 desc, 1 asc;`
```

The table, SalesRegister, has the following schema:

[SalesRegister Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7pOz.png)

Using this query

```
“select CaseNumber, CaseYear, CaseMonth from SalesRegister where CarrierName like 'Grange%' order by CaseYear desc, CaseMonth asc”,
```

the table, SalesRegister, has the following entries for CarrierName ‘Grange%’:

```
CaseNumber      CaseYear    CaseMonth
24000A019467    2020            4
24000A019468    2020            4
24000A014820    2019            1
24000A015307    2019            3
24000A015308    2019            3
24000A015552    2019            4
24000A015728    2019            4
WEB00A671142    2019            4
WEB00A668109    2019            5
24000A016137    2019            6
WEB00A866344    2019            11
```

You will note that there are 9 CaseNumbers from 2019 and 2 CaseNumbers from 2020.  There are no CaseNumbers from either 2021 or 2022.

However, when I execute the query shown at the top of this question, I get the following results:

Carrier ID  CarrierName     2022        2021        2020
9761        Grange          1       1       3

When I execute the following queries for each of the years needed (2022, 2021 & 2020):

select CaseYear, count(CaseNumber) from SalesRegister
where CarrierName like 'Grange%' and CaseYear = '2020'
group by CaseYear;

I get the correct results, but when I use the “CASE” function shown in the query at the top of this question, I get the anomalous / incorrect results.

My question – how does the top query (using the CASE function) produce the incorrect results?  Is the syntax wrong?  Is the GroupBy wrong?

I expected to receive accurate results, but the query is returning incorrect information.

Comment: In your `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` expression, you're also counting the zero (which is a distinct number).  I suggest changing it from `Else 0 end` to `Else NULL end`

Comment: Also, not sure what `order by 3 desc, 1 asc` is supposed to achieve.  These are just constant numbers, and so won't influence the order of results

Comment: @robeyre Numbers are treated as columns positions in the output columnset.

Comment: @Akina thanks for that.  First time I've seen it

Comment: Rob Eyre, Your suggestion did the trick.  Thanks so much for your input.